# Central repository url is not getting picked during maven build in eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, eclipse-oxygen

I have imported a maven project in Eclipse Oxygen.
I have added settings.xml to the eclipse as below:

**Windows -> Preference -> Maven -> User Setting -> browser to the the settings.xml**

Now settings.xml file is having url pointing to central repository(like: https://mydomain.cloud.repo/*) other than default maven central repository(https://repo.maven.apache.org/*). But when i am building my project as below, it is still trying to download the dependency from maven central repository but not the one updated in settings.xml.

**pom.xml -> right click run as -> maven install**

Can any one tell me what could be the reason and how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: Add your `settings.xml` to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going through a single maven repo, then make sure that you have

```
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html#using-a-single-repository